# PHPStorm reformat - how do I disable removing spaces in empty lines?

Tags: phpstorm, reformat

When reformatting a file, phpstorm replaces empty lines with whitespace to just empty lines, e.g. `^[tab][tab]$` to `^$`. How do I disable this?

Comment: Why do you care about spaces on empty lines?

Comment: Because some developers use IDEs which place tabs in empty lines, so reformat will remove these every time and add a lot of useless info to git diffs.

Comment: `diff` has an option to ignore whitespace differences. Doesn't `git diff` allow you to use that option?

Comment: Github doesn't seem to have that option I guess? Actually, I don't care if there are or are not spaces in empty lines, so I'd want phpstorm to act accordingly.

Comment: because, we can't always specify "ignore white spaces" on a git add/commit based on tools, and suddenly a 1-3 line correction submitted for review indicates half the file was changed!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

<s>You cannot -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-73161</s>

I was thinking that disabling stripping whitespace characters **altogether** would do the job:

> By changing `Settings | Editor | Strip trailing spaces on Save` (which nowadays has `Modified Lines` option)

but apparently it only works on "Save".

Related tickets:

- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-99173

---

Now you can do that **on code reformat** as well:

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Editor | Code Style`
3. `$language$ | Tabs and Indents | Keep indents on empty lines` check box

*(this option was introduced after this answer was provided: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103941#comment=27-807213)*

Comment: I've set "strip trailing spaces on Save" to "None". But reformat still acts as I've described originally. Is this expected?

Comment: "Yes" and "No" at the same time. "Yes" because right now it cannot be avoided (for whatever reason -- see above mentioned ticket IDEA-73161) and "No" because I would expect that the above option to work even during reformat. I will alter my answer a bit.

Comment: Is it possible to disable striping spaces on `.blade.php` files, but enable it for all other files (including index.php etc.) ?

Comment: @Adam Using `.editorconfig` file (it has standard option fir such stuff) & enabled EditorConfig support in IDE settings -- yes, that should work fine (even on per file level, if configured properly). NOTE: When enabled, settings from `.editorconfig` **override** IDE settings.

Answer (score 2):

I find solution in opposite topic: [Configure editor to remove whitespaces in blank lines](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205803079-Configure-editor-to-remove-whitespaces-in-blank-lines).

It works in **WebStorm**, and should work in **PHPStorm** as well:

`Settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP | Tabs and Indents (tab) | Keep Indents on Empty Lines" (check box)`